# accessing a static dict in Python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, enums, static, static-methods

I have an Enum class of compass directions as follows.
I also have an 'opposites' dict declared in the same class.

```
from enum import Enum

class Compass(Enum):
    N = 'N'  # North
    S = 'S'  # South
    E = 'E'  # East
    W = 'W'  # West
    opposites = {N: S, S: N, E: W, W: E}

    # static method to provide the opposite values.
    @staticmethod
    def other(com):
        return opposites[com]
```

when I attempt to call other, eg.  Compass.other(Compass.N), I expect to get Compass.S, but instead I am getting..

```
TypeError: 'Com' object is not subscriptable
```

What's going on, and how can I remedy this pythonically ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic problem is that `opposite` is being transformed into an `Enum` member just like `N`, `S,`E, and `W` are.  The next problem is the values in `opposite` -- they do *not* get transformed into `Enum` members.

Ideally, we would have something like:

```
# NB: does not currently work!

class Compass(Enum):
    N = 'N', S
    S = 'S', N
    E = 'E', W
    W = 'W', E

Compass.E.opposite is Compass.W  # True
```

The reasons this does not currently work are twofold:

- the final transformation from plain value to `Enum` member happens after the class has been created
- forward references are not allowed

So, to get a clean(er) implementation and API we have to post-process the `Enum`.  I would use a decorator:

```
class reverse():
    "decorator to add reverse lookups to Enum members"

    def __init__(self, reverse_map):
        "initialize decorator by saving map"
        self.reverse_map = reverse_map

    def __call__(self, enum):
        "apply map to newly created Enum"
        for first, second in self.reverse_map.items():
            enum[first].opposite = enum[second]
            enum[second].opposite = enum[first]
        # don't forget to return the now-decorated Enum
        return enum
```

and in use:

```
@reverse({'N':'S', 'E':'W'})
class Compass(Enum):
    N = 'N'  # North
    S = 'S'  # South
    E = 'E'  # East
    W = 'W'  # West

>>> Compass.N.opposite is Compass.S
True
```

Comment: This is so cool. I learned more Python from this answer than in the last few days.

Comment: @Konchog:  High praise!  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

@RomanPerekhrest got the credit for this purely due to speed of response, but it took a bit more wrangling to get what I wanted, which was an enum from the class. The cast to the Enum itself raises an error if bad input is put into it..

The class file folloeinh RomanPerekhrest that worked for me looks like this.

```
from enum import Enum

class Compass(Enum):
    N = 'N'  # North
    S = 'S'  # South
    E = 'E'  # East
    W = 'W'  # West
    _opposites = {N: S, S: N, E: W, W: E}

    @staticmethod
    def other(item):
        return Compass(Compass._opposites.value[item.value])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(Compass.other(Compass.E))
```

However, @EthanFurman's response is beautiful, and I actually implemented that, not that I completely understand it yet...

Answer (score 1):

Your custom class `Compass` is derived from `Enum` class which is *enumeration* but not subscriptable sequence.

Consider this line:

```
print(type(Compass.N))
```

While you expect it to output `<class 'str'>` - it outputs:

```
<enum 'Compass'>
```

To access *enumaration* object property use `value` attribute.

```
print(Compass.N.value)           # prints "N"
print(Compass.opposites.value)   # prints {'S': 'N', 'N': 'S', 'E': 'W', 'W': 'E'}
```

---

A proper `Compass.other()` function declaration should look as below:

```
    # static method to provide the opposite values.
    @staticmethod
    def other(item):
        if item in Compass.opposites.value:
            return Compass.opposites.value[item]
        else:
            raise AttributeError('unknown compass direction :', item)
```

Usage:

```
print(Compass.other(Compass.N.value))  # prints "S"
```